# calculate the value of dropdown if I switch the toggle in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to calculate a simple result with a toggle and dropdown

```
    <ion-toggle (ionChange)="result()" [(ngModel)]="ShowVip"></ion-toggle>
    
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="VipPeriod" (ionChange)="selectOption($event)">
    <ion-option value="1">ONE</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">TWO</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="result()" [(ngModel)]="ShowPremum"></ion-toggle>

 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="PremumPeriod" (ionChange)="selectOption($event)">
    <ion-option value="1">ONE</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">TWO</ion-option>
    </ion-select>


<div>{{Total}}= {{VipPeriod}}+{{PremumPeriod}}</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "calculate"? Please don't just post code, but instead describe the problem that you are having and what the desired outcome is.

Comment: @Daniel B Sorry for misunderstanding , I mean Sum the value of two dropdown

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that then. A hint, if you expect the sum to be displayed in the `div`,  why have you split up the calculation into two different parts? The plus sign will be considered a `string` as you have it right now, not an arithmetic operator.

Comment: @Daniel B Ok do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You have to really specify what you want. For instance, what is the purpose of `<div>{{Total}}= {{VipPeriod}}+{{PremumPeriod}}</div>`? Is it supposed to show a formula, or do you expect it to calculate it and show the result? Where is `Total` defined?

Modify your question to actually include a question, like _"When both options are selected, I want to call a function that calculates the values of the dropdowns, and assigns the value to the variable `Total`. How do I do that?"_. Right now there's no clear question, which makes it hard to reply in a good way.

Comment: @Daniel B Sorry for misunderstanding , I just need to display the Total if one or both selected